# Execute PHP file from HTML; Visitor Counter

Tags: php, html, counter

Here is a copy of the PHP code I am running.

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "adn") or ("die");



    $visitorIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $savedIPs = "SELECT `IPAddress` FROM `ipaddresses`;";
    $uniqueCounter = "SELECT `uniqueCount` FROM `counter`;";
    $visitorCounter = "SELECT `count` FROM `counter`;";
    $insert = "INSERT INTO IPADDRESSES (`IPAddress`) VALUES ($visitorIP);";
    $count1 = $uniqueCounter;
    $count2 = $visitorCounter;

    $update1 = "UPDATE `counter` SET `uniqueCount` = $count1;";
    $update2 = "UPDATE `counter` SET `count` = $count2;";

    if($visitorIP != $savedIPs) {
        $count1++;
        $count2++;
        mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
        mysqli_query($conn,$update1);
    }
    else{
        $count2++;
        mysqli_query($conn,$update2);
    }

?>
```

The connection to the SQL database, the table names and column names are spelled correctly.  **PROBLEM:** I want this to run whenever someone visits our website at the `.com` address causing the webserver to send the `index.html` page out.  How do I link this file to run whenever the `index.html` file is accessed over the web?

Running on XAMPP Apache server.  PHP server running in background.  I've tried creating an `.htaccess` file to allow execution of php within the html file but is still not recognized by the VS Code IDE.

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "adn") or ("die");



    $visitorIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $savedIPs = "SELECT `IPAddress` FROM `ipaddresses`;";
    $uniqueCounter = "SELECT `uniqueCount` FROM `counter`;";
    $visitorCounter = "SELECT `count` FROM `counter`;";
    $insert = "INSERT INTO IPADDRESSES (`IPAddress`) VALUES ($visitorIP);";
    $count1 = $uniqueCounter;
    $count2 = $visitorCounter;

    $update1 = "UPDATE `counter` SET `uniqueCount` = $count1;";
    $update2 = "UPDATE `counter` SET `count` = $count2;";

    if($visitorIP != $savedIPs) {
        $count1++;
        $count2++;
        mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
        mysqli_query($conn,$update1);
    }
    else{
        $count2++;
        mysqli_query($conn,$update2);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can you show how you modified the htaccess? Also you are SQL injectable, parameterize. Your `update`s also could be written as 1 query, and you likely don't need any of the selects. `insert into... on duplicate ...`.

Comment: The .htaccess content is....


AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

Comment: Do I need to edit any of the Apach config files to allow this?

Comment: Ok. So I've abandoned trying to get PHP code to work in an HTML file.  Instead I have re-saved the index page as index.php.  Turns out you have to NOT be dumb enough to have your apache server on, yet be working from a copy of the project in directory apache isn't using, all while viewing it via VS-Code's live server.  Just doesn't work.